# How to redirect to a page according to the first letter written into an input field (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have this form:

```
<form action="redirect.php" method="post" id="mainForm">
<input name="name" type="text" class="false" id="name" maxlength="10" />
<input type="submit" id="send" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Now, when you write words starting with an **a** as first letter, I want the user to be redirected to **first.php**; if you write words starting with a **b** you will be redirected to **second.php**; and if you write **anything else** that start with any letter but **not an a or b** you will be redirected to **third.php**.

How can I do that? And how do I implement it in my redirect.php? What I mean is that when you will be redirected I will receive your name too, actually I use `header('Location:` after `@mail` function, but I redirect to only one page.

Comment: @Thomas Please forgive my writing and grammar! I just want to give examples! Anyway thanks for correction. And thanks for the minus!

Comment: I did not know that I have to know English grammar! Sorry for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $name=trim($_POST["name"]);
}else{
    // no name input.. REDIRECT back to the form?  
}
if (strtolower(substr($name,0,1)) == 'a'){
     // REDIRECT To FIRST 
}elseif (strtolower(substr($name,0,1))=='b'){
     // REDIRECT TO seconde
}else{
     // REDIRECT to third 
}
```

See if it works for you..

Comment: If is no name input will alert the user, and your code must be replaced with the header function in my redirect.php file ? Thanks.

Comment: I would assume you replace in how you want to redirect the page. And there is no such thing as too many verification... Even if you have JS verification on the front end, it is still a good practice to have a back end verification as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you give me the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name'] && strlen($_POST['name']) > 0) {
   // send to first letter ($_POST['name'][0]
   switch($_POST['name'][0]) {
      case 'a':
      case 'A':
         // if the first letter is a or A
         header('Location: http://www.example.com/first.php');
         break;
      case 'b':
      case 'B':
         // otherwise if the first letter is b or B
         header('Location: http://www.example.com/second.php');
         break;
      default:
         // if none of the above
         header('Location: http://www.example.com/somePlace/third.php');
   }
} else {
   // if no name was supplied
   header('Location: http://www.example.com/somePlace/noLetterSelected');
}
exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_POST['name']))
    $input = $_POST['name'];

function directMe($input)
{
        $firstChar = strtolower(substr($input, 0, 1));
        if ($firstChar == 'a')
            header('Location: ...first.php');
        elseif ($firstChar == 'b')
            header('Location: ...second.php');
        else
            header('Location: ...third.php');
}

directMe($input);
```